# Converting ImageCombo from VB6 to Vb.Net shows simple non Editable Textbox

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I have the following code written in Vb6 for ImageCombo control.

```
Begin MSComctlLib.ImageCombo dImageCombo 
      Height          =   330
      Index           =   0
      Left            =   120
      TabIndex        =   10
      Top             =   3480
      Visible         =   0   'False
      Width           =   1815
      _ExtentX        =   3201
      _ExtentY        =   582
      _Version        =   393216
      ForeColor       =   -2147483640
      BackColor       =   -2147483643
      Text            =   "ImageCombo1"
   End
```

Then I have a RenderCombo function as follows. It goes through each and every line of function and get a proper value as well for ItemList in ImageCombo but doesn't display anything. It simply appear as a Non Editable Textview.

```
Private Sub RenderCombo(a_dbmgr As ObjectDBManager, _
        ByRef a_X As Integer, ByRef a_Y As Integer, _
        bnode As DataSetNode, fldname As String, _
        MaxPixHeight As Integer, ColMaxWidth As Integer, _
        hLevels As Integer, YStart As Integer, gHeight As Integer, _
        padding As Integer, gInframe As Boolean, a_tooltip As String)
    Dim tstr As String
    Dim ltmp As ComboItem
    Dim lseldata As String
    Dim loldcolwidth As Integer

    Load dImageCombo(nCombos + 1)
    nCombos = nCombos + 1

    tstr = bnode.GetLeafString("WIDTH")
    If tstr <> "" Then
        dImageCombo(nCombos).Width = SafeCLng(tstr)
    End If



            dImageCombo(nCombos).Visible = True
            dImageCombo(nCombos).Left = a_X
            dImageCombo(nCombos).Top = a_Y
            lseldata = bnode.GetLeafString("SELTABLENAV") & "+" & _
                bnode.GetLeafString("SELMATCHFIELD") & "+" & _
                bnode.GetLeafString("SELMATCHNAV") & "+" & _
                bnode.GetLeafString("SELLABELNAME") & "+" & _
                bnode.GetLeafString("SELNOBLANK") & "+" & _
                bnode.GetLeafString("SELVALCAPS") & "+"

            dImageCombo(nCombos).Tag = fldname & "+" & lseldata 


            mMakeComboList a_dbmgr, bnode, nCombos, lseldata


            SetNextXY a_X, a_Y, dImageCombo(nCombos).Width, dImageCombo(nCombos).Height, _
                MaxPixHeight, gHeight, hLevels, YStart, ColMaxWidth, loldcolwidth, "COMBO", gInframe
            If gInframe Then

                dFrame(nFrames).Width = mBumpWidth(dFrame(nFrames).Width, dImageCombo(nCombos).Left + loldcolwidth + padding, "COMBO")
                Set dImageCombo(nCombos).Container = dFrame(nFrames)
            End If
            dImageCombo(nCombos).ToolTipText = a_tooltip

End Sub
```

Code that I've got in VB.Net after migration is as follows:

```
Private Sub RenderCombo(ByRef a_dbmgr As ObjectDBManager, ByRef a_X As Short, ByRef a_Y As Short, ByRef bnode As DataSetNode, ByRef fldname As String, ByRef MaxPixHeight As Short, ByRef ColMaxWidth As Short, ByRef hLevels As Short, ByRef YStart As Short, ByRef gHeight As Short, ByRef padding As Short, ByRef gInframe As Boolean, ByRef a_tooltip As String)
        Dim tstr As String = "" 
        Dim ltmp As MSComctlLib.ComboItem
        Dim lseldata As String = "" 
        Dim loldcolwidth As Short

        dImageCombo.Load(nCombos + 1)
        nCombos = nCombos + 1

        tstr = bnode.GetLeafString("WIDTH")
        If tstr <> "" Then
            dImageCombo(nCombos).Width = SafeCLng(tstr)
        End If


            dImageCombo(nCombos).Visible = True
            dImageCombo(nCombos).Left = a_X
            dImageCombo(nCombos).Top = a_Y
            lseldata = bnode.GetLeafString("SELTABLENAV") & "+" & bnode.GetLeafString("SELMATCHFIELD") & "+" & bnode.GetLeafString("SELMATCHNAV") & "+" & bnode.GetLeafString("SELLABELNAME") & "+" & bnode.GetLeafString("SELNOBLANK") & "+" & bnode.GetLeafString("SELVALCAPS") & "+"

            dImageCombo(nCombos).Tag = fldname & "+" & lseldata 


            mMakeComboList(a_dbmgr, bnode, nCombos, lseldata)

            SetNextXY(a_X, a_Y, dImageCombo(nCombos).Width, dImageCombo(nCombos).Height, MaxPixHeight, gHeight, hLevels, YStart, ColMaxWidth, loldcolwidth, "COMBO", gInframe)
            If gInframe Then

                dFrame(nFrames).Width = mBumpWidth(dFrame(nFrames).Width, dImageCombo(nCombos).Left + loldcolwidth + padding, "COMBO")
                dImageCombo(nCombos).Parent = dFrame(nFrames)
            End If
            ToolTip1.SetToolTip(dImageCombo(nCombos), a_tooltip)

    End Sub
```

Designer code after migration:

```
Friend WithEvents dImageCombo As AxImageComboArray
Friend WithEvents _dImageCombo_0 As AxMSComctlLib.AxImageCombo
Me._dImageCombo_0 = New AxMSComctlLib.AxImageCombo
Me.dImageCombo = New AxImageComboArray(Me.components)
   CType(Me._dImageCombo_0, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()
CType(Me.dImageCombo, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).BeginInit()

        Me.dImageCombo.SetIndex(Me._dImageCombo_0, CType(0, Short))
        Me._dImageCombo_0.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(8, 232)
        Me._dImageCombo_0.Name = "_dImageCombo_0"
        Me._dImageCombo_0.OcxState = CType(resources.GetObject("_dImageCombo_0.OcxState"), System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)
        Me._dImageCombo_0.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(121, 22)
        Me._dImageCombo_0.TabIndex = 10
        Me._dImageCombo_0.Visible = False
Me.Controls.Add(Me._dImageCombo_0)
CType(Me._dImageCombo_0, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
CType(Me.dImageCombo, System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize).EndInit()
```

[Here is the screenshot of ImageCombo that display as a simple TextBox in Vb.Net.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7dfdp.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might be better off rewriting some of the old app to use the new NET elements rather than those Ax wrappers.  For a CBO or ListBox to show images would require a little work (and some research if you are not NET savvy), but an `OwnerDraw` list control requires less code than that `RenderCombo` method.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: @Plutonix Problem I got here is It doesn't appear as a dropdown. It simply shows as a TextView. It adds items in list and executes code well but doesn't appear as a DropDown. I am not sure if there is any problem with designer properties !!

Comment: Yeah, I understood the problem.  The point is that the app would benefit from using NET solutions.  A ListView might work and if not, I know there is code here to show how to implement an `OwnerDraw` CBO - and might even be easier than fixing your Ax issue. Also note that Control Arrays are another VB6ism you would do well to abandon.  [Ask] and the [Tour] are still available